# Can I test my DJI SDK for Windows 10 application with a DJI Drone simulator without the risk of running a real DJI Drone?

Tags: dji-sdk

Can I test my DJI SDK for Windows 10 application with a DJI Drone simulator without the risk of running a real DJI Drone?

I am asking since it is cumbersome to have developers run a real drone in their office to test what they are building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to test applications but both require a physical drone.

1) Download and install the PC Simulator; this is a game-engine that connects the PC (USB) to a drone and displays the flight operations.  It is available online under the developer downloads.

2) Using the API, you can enable simulator.  This method is not as good because you cannot see in real-time what the aircraft is doing unless you receive and display flight details within your app.

Both act the same to the PC simulator can be easier to evaluate and observe the flight operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your drone in a simulator mode using the APIs.

This will make your drone respond as if it was flying, but the motors won't turn on.
After that, you can use the DJI Assistant to visualize the aircraft moving in a simulated 3D environment.

Comment: Thank you for help. Is there any way to do that without a physical Drone?

Comment: Not at this time.

Comment: Is there any *long-term* way to have a physical DJI drone hooked up to a computer in simulator mode? Hoping to find a solution that allows for a simulated drone to be part of continuous integration tests. As it stands, having the drone run off of rechargeable batteries is not viable.